# Getting empty result when trying to fetch the output of AVAssetExportSession from PHAsset

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avfoundation, phasset

I'm attempting to build a small toy iOS app that merges two video assets from the user's photos library. I've gotten to the point where I have merged the videos using an `AVMutableComposition` instance and now I need to export the composition. I am doing so with the following code:

```
func saveEditedComposition(_ composition: AVMutableComposition) {
    let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    let savePath = (documentDirectory as NSString).strings(byAppendingPaths: ["mergeVideo.mov"])[0]
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: savePath)

    // Set up exporter
    guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else { return }
    exporter.outputURL = url as URL
    exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
    exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

    // Perform the export
    exporter.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: { () -> Void in
        // Upon completion of the export, 
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            if exporter.status == .completed {
                let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [exporter.outputURL!], options: nil))
                let phAsset = fetchResult.firstObject! // Crashes here, returning nil.
            }
        }
    })
}
```

The problem is, when the completionHandler is run, I am able to see that my exporter has completed without error (`if exporter.status == .completed {`), but when I try to access the asset at `exporter.outputURL`, it returns an empty `PHFetchResult<PHAsset>`. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're exporting the video to the file system (the Documents directory), yet fetching from the camera roll/`ALAssetsLibrary`.

It depends on what you need to do with the exported file. If it needs to be in the `ALAssetsLibrary`, you can use

```
ALAssetsLibrary().writeVideoAtPath(toSavedPhotosAlbum: exporter.outputURL!) { alAssetURL, error in      
}
```

However `ALAssetsLibrary` is now deprecated and you are supposed to use `PHPhotoLibrary`. I don't know the Photos framework, but I *think* it works like this:

```
var placeHolder: PHObjectPlaceholder?

PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
    let changeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: exporter.outputURL!)
    if let changeRequest = changeRequest {
        // maybe set date, location & favouriteness here?
        placeHolder = changeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset
    }
}) { success, error in
    placeHolder?.localIdentifier    // should identify asset from now on?
}
```

If you don't need the video to live in the camera roll, then you can work directly with the file in `exporter.outputURL!`.